# How to get logged in user in adonis js websocket controller

Tags: websocket, adonis.js

I am trying to get the current logged in user details in a websocket controller. I tried like this

```
constructor ({ socket, request , auth}) {
   this.socket = socket
   this.request = request
   this.auth=auth

}
async onClose (data) {
   const user = await this.auth.user 
   console.log(user) // it gives null
}
```

I get null. How can I get the user details?

Thank you.

Comment: Which adonis version are you using?

Comment: 4.1 the latest one.

Comment: Before using `auth.user`, you need to execute `await auth.check()` first. It will check authorisation and set the authorized user as `.user`. Another way is using `const user = await auth.getUser()`, it does the same job.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Could you please show me how you would do to get user id in a socket controller? Thank you @vietanhyt

Answer (score -1):

Since you have assigned auth object to controller's auth variable, i assume you have added the middleware to the routes in the socket.js file. if you have done that already, you can try the following line

```
 async onClose (data) {
   //const user = await this.auth.user 
   const user = this.auth.user // this.auth.user will give you anything you want
   const id = user.id
   const name = user.name 
   console.log(user) // it will console the authenticated user details
}
```

Hope it will help.